# Change array in array in document via mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've got such schema:

```
username: String,
authData: socialNetworkName: {
        access_token: String,
        expiration_date: Date,
        id: String
    }
```

And example of using it:

```
"name" : "Ilya",
"authData" : {
    "fb" : {
        "access_token" : "ECBAI3easd64T4dEokBaANN",
        "expiration_date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T18:55:07Z"),
        "id" : "4314342324242424242"
    },
    "twitter": {
        "access_token":"fdfkdlfdfdfkdl",
        "expiration_date":ISODate("2017-02-01T18:55:07Z",
        "id":"343243434"
    }
},
```

How do I access `fb` in `authData` in order to update access token without changing 'twitter'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $set operator to update the value of the fb access_token.
You can use the dotted path to access the update-able field of your document.

```
db.yourcollection.update( 
    {name:'Ilya'}, 
    { $set: {"authData.fb.token":"fbtoken"} } )
```

Comment: Works just as needed. Thanks!